# How to extend default implementation (with an extension) adding a didSet on a property?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How can I implement `didSet` on MyProtocol `var` through an extension?

I need to run some specific code after it has been set.

I tried this, but I get this error:

> Extensions may not contain stored properties

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var contact: MyContact? { get set }
}

extension MyProtocol {
    var contact: MyContact? {
        didSet {
            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the docs:

> Extensions can add new computed properties, but they cannot add stored properties, or add property observers to existing properties.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151

If you want to set a default value of `contact`, then it has to be a computed property.

```
extension MyProtocol {
  var contact: MyContact? {
    return MyContact()
  }
}
```

Comment: then I guess you will have to add the observer in the objects that conform to your protocol.

Comment: If they are Objective-C classes, you could use key-value observing.